# Sum Data in SQL by a column

Tags: sql

I am looking to add a common value.

My table has the following data:

```
Customer:     $ Value:
123           100.00
123           100.00
abc           100.00
abc           100.00
```

I want it to display as:

```
Customer:  $ Value:
123        200.00
abc        200.00
```

There are a number of other columns too that contain various different dates etc but they are not relevant here.

Comment: And your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Customer, SUM(Value)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` Clause and the aggregate function `SUM()`.

For more info about `GROUP BY` refer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

```
SELECT Customer, SUM(Value) AS Value FROm table GROUP BY Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
SELECT 
    Customer,
    SUM(Value) AS Value 
FROM 
    Table1 
GROUP BY 
    Customer
```